# How do I ensure a user has a home directory at the default location of /home/new-user and uses the default shell /bin/bash

Tags: users

I'm trying to create a new user which I understand you use useradd [filename]

Then I need to ensure this user has a home directory at a default location of `/home/filename` and uses the default shell `/bin/bash`.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

we can get the details from `/etc/passwd`

```
 grep <username> /etc/passwd
```

to get the details of admin user:

```
awk -F ':' '/^admin:/ {print "home Directory: "$6 "\nDefault shell: "$7}' /etc/passwd

home Directory: /home/admin
Default shell: /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

The user creation scripts for your distribution (usually called `useradd` or similar, check documentation!) should take care of that.

Stepping back, what exactly do you want? There might be an easy answer...